# Is Hypertable production ready?

Tags: hbase, hypertable

Is Hypertable production ready? I can find very little information online. It seems everyone uses HBase instead however Hypertable claims to be much faster.

Comment: Tip: If you can find very little information online, I wouldn't recommend using it for production just yet...

Comment: Not true at all. The more "Enterprise" something is the less usage it will get from normal users and thus the less you will find about it online.

Comment: The causal relationship between product being enterprise class and therefore lacking online documentation is not as straightforward. Consider IBM db2 or IBM Websphere - both have extensive documentation available online. On the other hand, you have IBM zOS - it is certainly well documented, but little of it is available online. Reason being is that zOS architecture has little competition being a closely-guarded system. So I think the criteria is - if product is unique and the ecosystem is closed - you'll see no publicly available documentation. Things are different for OSS.

Comment: In NoSql community, I have heard very little or nothing about Hypertable in last 2 years. Not sure about the status of project. 
PS: I have been working on HBase for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Hypertable is production ready. Baidu chinese search engine is using Hypertable extensively for their applications. The sad thing is that there is no much support community around hypertable.